# Python - os.system - entering command line with multiple file paths (alternatives to r"C:\etc")

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

What is the best way to enter the following into windows command line from Python 3? There are three filepaths in the command that must be entered in one line (I believe).

`"C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\ANSYS Student\v194\Framework\bin\Win64\runwb2" -B -F "E:\MEngA\Ansys\IFD_PartA_Rev3.wbpj" -R "E:\MEngA\Results\sn07\script_partA.wbjn"`

It needs the quote marks. Currently trying:

`os.system('"C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\ANSYS Student\v194\Framework\bin\Win64\runwb2" -B -F "E:\MEngA\Ansys\IFD_PartA_Rev3.wbpj" -R "E:\MEngA\Results\sn07\script_partA.wbjn"')`

but the spaces cause problems:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

using r before the filepath worked when just trying:
`os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\ANSYS Student\v194\Framework\bin\Win64\runwb2")`

but doesn't work with the full string. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: If you don't use raw strings, and also don't escape your backslashes by doubling them up, then Python doesn't know that your backslashes are supposed to be passed through to the child process, rather than interpreted as referring to special characters. To give you examples of what I mean by that, remember that `\t` is not a backslash-then-a-`t` but rather a single tab character, and `\n` is not a backslash-then-a-`n` but only a single newline character. Thus, when you want to tell Python that a backslash "is just a backslash", you either need to double it up, or put it in a "raw" string.

Comment: Anyhow, using `os.system()` is considered bad practice in the first place. `subprocess.run()` and other calls in the `Popen()` family are supposed to be used instead in new code -- pass a list rather than a string and then the Python interpreter, rather than the code you're writing, is responsible for knowing how to pass data to the operating system (or, for Windows, the standard C library's command-line parser in the called program's memory space) in a way it'll correctly interpret.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you post an example of how to structure this with a suitable function from sub.process.run() or Popen() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) which accepts a list of strings that together compose the full command. Since your paths contain backslashes you can use `r''` in order to get the raw string. The first path also contains spaces and hence needs to be wrapped in additional quotes `""`.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run([
    r'"C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\ANSYS Student\v194\Framework\bin\Win64\runwb2"',
     '-B',
     '-F',
    r'E:\MEngA\Ansys\IFD_PartA_Rev3.wbpj',
     '-R',
    r'E:\MEngA\Results\sn07\script_partA.wbjn',
])
```

Comment: Thanks, the example of structure is much appreciated. I now have "[WinError 5] Access is denied" but will try and work this out myself..

Comment: @JosephLangley This indeed sounds like a different issue.

Comment: It's possible this is an administrator rights thing. Any ideas on how to run the above as administrator? @a_guest

Comment: @JosephLangley I guess that makes a question of its own (maybe it has been asked before already).